# Ubuntu in Virtual Box - Desktop shows in preview but not in actual Virtual Box

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, .desktop, previews

Brand new around here. Installed ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit due to system reqs) for VirtualBox. Booted up the desktop, but it's only showing in the preview mode - the actual VirtualBox is a blank purple background.

When I move mouse around, it is tracked in the preview mode, and I can open files, etc. However the VirtualBox remains blank.

Screenshot attached, with preview box on the left and actual virtualbox on the right.

Any experience with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to grow video memory of your Ubuntu virtual machine from 12MB to 128MB.

To do so:

- Stop your VM;
- Open VM settings (*right-click on VM from virtual machines list and select settings*);
- Select **Display** entry and move video memory slider from 12MB to 128MB;
- Also tick **Enable 3D Acceleration** to improve your VM performance.

I also suggest to you to install *Virtual Box Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack* and *Guest Additions*.

You can find the first package on [Virtual Box official website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), then select the right version according to your Virtual Box version and once you have downloaded the file, simple double-click on it and follow the installation procedure.

To install *Guest Additions* start your VM and login into Ubuntu. Then from VM window menu select *Device* > *Install Guest Additions*. It will load a virtual CD into your Ubuntu VM and should open a terminal (If not, open the CD manually). Then run the script following the instruction. At the end you have to reboot VM to see results.

*Guest Additions* are useful because they add some driver and system applications that optimize the guest operative system.

Comment: @kneuman Good! Could you accept the answer? In this way other people with similar issues could use a verified answer. Thanks