# Problem with resolution of Ubuntu 14 on Windows7 x64 Virtualbox5

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, display-resolution

I'm running Windows7 x64, Virtualbox 5.0.16 and just installed Ubuntu 14.04.

Ubuntu starts fine, but gives a very low resolution (e.g. 640x460).

I tried running `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`

but this gives me the error

> Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-x11: depends on xorg-video abi-15
>   depends on xserver-xorg-core etc.etc.

I'm stuck here. Any suggestions (using newbie language?)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried to install Virtualbox `guest additions`? You can find more information on how install it at this link (see the answer): http://askubuntu.com/questions/752742/ubuntu-in-virtual-box-desktop-shows-in-preview-but-not-in-actual-virtual-box/752756

Comment: I tried installing it via the terminal, but this failed (see above). Also, installed the Iso, but can't find a way to mount it. And, where do I find 'Device' in  Device > Install Guest Additions???

Comment: `Device` is in the Virtualbox window menu. If your virtual machine is fullscreen you can exit it by pressing right ctrl+f. Now you can see the windows menu on the top left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first you need to download the VirtualBox 5.0.17 Guest Additions installer image from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).
(P.S.: make sure you download one for Linux 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the system you installed on your VM)

After that add this image into your VM's DVD and start your VM.

When booted up and logged in you might need to mount the cd image (in case you use a server image of Ubuntu) and aswell need some software to install.

```
# Run those commands if youre using Ubuntu server
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom

# The following you need always
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```